# Strtotime has one hour advance on some dates?

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

why do some dates on `strtotime()` has one our advance?

I have a code(this is correct output for some dates please see explanation):

```
$date =  strtotime($_POST['date'])-3600;
$date35 = $date*1000;
```

which converts properly to my timezone, but from dates (as i have observed) in days of month 25 to 31, it's one hour advance? but on dates of the month that is below 25 or 24 below, the hour is ok?

i tried to manipulate buy adding formula but it can affect other rows that is below 24 days, what should i do?

however,  i can manipulate the display on My DATA TABLE by using this code:

```
 date('F j, Y'.' - '.' h:i A', $d / 1000+3600)
```

then the display is ok as echo, but on time, it's one hour advance, is their way that i can convert the date to timestamp oppositely from above code?

anyway, i have to use milliseconds because i am using https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar for my calendar.

This is my complete code:

```
<?php include('connect.php');
include('session.php'); ?>
{
"success": 1,
"result": [
        <?php
        $event_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointment,user,branch,service where user.user_id = appointment.user_id and appointment.branch_id = branch.branch_id and service.service_id = appointment.service_id  and appointment.appoint_date != (SELECT MAX(appointment.appoint_date) FROM appointment where appointment.branch_id = '$session_branchid')  and appointment.appoint_status='Pending' and appointment.branch_id = $session_branchid")or die(mysql_error());
          while($event_row = mysql_fetch_array($event_query)){
          $date = date($event_row['appoint_date']);

          $datee = date($event_row['end']);

          $uid = $event_row['user_id'];
          $appid = $event_row['appointment_id'];
          ?>
    {
        "id": "<?php echo $appid; ?>",
        "title": "<?php echo $event_row['firstname'].' '.$event_row['lastname']; ?>",
        "url": "client_appointment_modal.php?id=<?php echo $uid; ?>&si=<?php echo $event_row['service_id']; ?>",
        "class": "event-success",
        "start": "<?php echo  $date; ?>",
        "end":   "<?php echo $datee; ?>"
    }, 
    <?php }; ?>
    <?php
        $event_query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointment,user,branch,service where user.user_id = appointment.user_id and appointment.branch_id = branch.branch_id and service.service_id = appointment.service_id and appointment.appoint_status='Pending'  and appointment.branch_id = '$session_branchid' order by appointment.appoint_date desc limit 1")or die(mysql_error());
          while($event_row2 = mysql_fetch_array($event_query2)){
          $date = date($event_row2['appoint_date']);

          $datee = date($event_row2['end']);

          $uid2 = $event_row2['user_id'];
          $appid = $event_row2['appointment_id'];
          ?>
    {
        "id": "<?php echo $event_row2['appointment_id']; ?>",
        "title": "<?php echo $event_row2['firstname'].'  '.$event_row2['lastname']; ?>",
        "url": "client_appointment_modal.php?id=<?php echo $uid2; ?>&si= <?php echo $event_row2['service_id']; ?>",
        "class": "event-success",
        "start": "<?php echo  $date; ?>",
        "end":   "<?php echo $datee; ?>"
    }
    <?php }; ?>
]
}
```

this is the output:
[please see my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kMHl.jpg)

I am thinking it is because of strtotime? how to fix it?

Comment: @SubinThomas edited the question, please see

Comment: from the above, it is what i use to insert in the data base, dates from 24 below are ok, but 25 to 31 is hour advance please see the image

Comment: <td><?php echo date('F j, Y'.' - '.' h:i A', $d / 1000+3600).' to '.date('h:i A', $end / 1000+3600); ?></td> but not inside the complete code for calendar

Comment: @SubinThomas <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-7" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                    <input class="form-control" size="16" name="date" type="text" value="" readonly> this is what i use for date time picking, but it works on some dates below 24? and this is what i use to insert $date =  strtotime($_POST['date'])-3600;
$date35 = $date*1000;

Comment: yes to DB, i converted unix timestamp from data base and it is really 1 hour advance starting from days 25 to 31, is i subtract an hour to it, other days will be affected, i am thinking of adding if condition? how? @SubinThomas

Comment: Show me that code. How you get input and process it.?? Show that code. Other details are not required.

Comment: @SubinThomas this is what i use to insert in the DB $date =  strtotime($_POST['date'])-3600; $date35 = $date*1000;

Comment: this is from day 24, 8 am selected 1445752811000 and day 25, 1445839243000 and 26, 1445662805000, all is selected to 8 am , but 25 also 26 ++ display 9 am @SubinThomas

Comment: i think its because of daylight savings time? how can i fix it?

Comment: please see the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/6kMHl.jpg , i am thinking of setting date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); how should i apply it on datetimepicker?